# WebBrowser control and loadfinish

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I'm loading string to WebBrowser control, like so:

```
ArticleContent.NavigateToString("<p style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;'>" +article.Title + "</p><br/>" + article.Text);
```

article.Title and article.Text are just HTML strings.

So, when i navigate to this page i'm trying to show loading icon:

```
LoadingIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Then after loading data to WebBrowser control i disable the loading icon:

```
ArticleContent.NavigateToString("<p style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;'>" + article.Title + "</p><br/>" + article.Text);
loadingIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

**Problem is that loading icon disables earlier than WebBrowser content shows. Is there any event to handle on contentloaded or something...**

EDIT:

Event NAVIGATED works, but there is also a little delay...

Comment: did you try `LoadCompleted` event: `myBrowser.LoadCompleted += (s, e) => loadingIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`?

Comment: @dkozl `LoadCompleted` is an event on the XAML control but they want to know when the HTML has been rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .net code can't directly know when the embedded browser has finished rendering its contents.

If you rendered a whole HTML document you could use the `onload` event on the DOM to know when it has finished rendering. In that event you could then call back to your .net code using `window.external.Notify()` to execute a function which will change the visibility of the control.
It's a little more long-winded but will avoid displaying the control before the content has been rendered.